# Continously sum user inputs - JAVA

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, sum

Need help with summing continuous user inputs until 0 is input. Got pretty close. Just need to know what I'm missing.
Following is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a number");
            int number = in.nextInt();
            if (number == 0) {
                System.out.println("Okay thanks!");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("The current answer is :" + number);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not post images of code. Paste you code here.

Comment: Just create a variable before while loop and add into it. PS, refactor elseif into else because number that is not 0 is always !=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable and sum while the numbers are being entered.
following code and inline comment may help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum=0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        while (true) {          
            System.out.println("Enter a number");
             number= in.nextInt();
            if (number == 0) {
                System.out.println("Okay thanks!");
                break;
            } else {
                sum=sum+number;
                System.out.println("The current answer is :" + sum);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You do not want to re-declare the `Scanner` for every iteration of the loop

Answer (score 1):

Address the following problems in your code:

1. You must never instantiate `Scanner` inside a loop.
2. You need a variable e.g. `sum` to store the running sum of numbers.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number (0 to quit): ");
            int number = in.nextInt();
            if (number == 0) {
                System.out.println("Okay thanks!");
                break;
            }
            sum += number;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of numbers = " + sum);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a number (0 to quit): 10
Enter a number (0 to quit): 20
Enter a number (0 to quit): 30
Enter a number (0 to quit): 0
Okay thanks!
Sum of numbers = 60
```

Comment: Yay, at last an answer having the correct placement/scope of variables

Comment: Thanks, @ScaryWombat for the encouragement.

Answer (score -1):

More optimize code:
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Task3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0, number = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a number");
            number = in.nextInt();
            sum = sum + number;
        } while (number != 0);
        System.out.println("The current answer is :" + sum);
    }

}
```